# How to represent a set of variables are different elements of a set mathematically?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Lets say that we have set $A$. The variables $m_{1}$, $m_{2}$, $\cdots$  $m_{N}$ are elements of the set $A$ but with exclusivity. The variables have to be different elements of the set. How can I represent it mathematically?

Can I just write $m_1, m_2, \cdots m_N \in A$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can say $m_1, m_2, \dotsc, m_N \in A$ are such that $m_i \neq m_j$ for any $i \neq j$.

Comment: Ofcourse. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

"Let $m_1,m_2,\ldots, m_N$ be distinct elements of $A$."